# native-maven-plugin jni osx pom

Tags: maven, java-native-interface, native-maven-plugin

I'm trying add a JNI library written in c/cpp to a java project.  The java project is called Subsonic, it's a media server.  I want to add support for .spc files so I wrote some JNI to make that happen.  I just don't understand maven very well.

This is the directory structure:

```
subsonic/
    gme/
        *.cpp
        snes.c -->contains C jni code

subsonic-main/
    ...
    src/main/java/net/sourceforge/subsonic/service/metadata/
        GMEMetaDataParser.java -->contains the JNI calls
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make maven work with me.  This is my current pom file:

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>gme</artifactId>
<name>JNI Libraries for Subsonic</name>
<packaging>dylib</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.subsonic</groupId>
    <artifactId>subsonic</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.beta1</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <!--  trigger javah -->
                <javahOS>macosx</javahOS>
                <compilerProvider>generic-classic</compilerProvider>
                <compilerExecutable>gcc</compilerExecutable>
                <linkerExecutable>gcc</linkerExecutable>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <directory>./</directory>
                        <fileNames>
                            <fileName>snes.c</fileName>
                            <fileName>Ay_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Ay_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Ay_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Blip_Buffer.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Classic_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Data_Reader.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Dual_Resampler.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Effects_Buffer.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Fir_Resampler.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gb_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gb_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gb_Oscs.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gbs_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gme_File.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Gym_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Hes_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Hes_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Hes_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Kss_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Kss_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Kss_Scc_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>M3u_Playlist.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Multi_Buffer.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Music_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Fme7_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Namco_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Oscs.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nes_Vrc6_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nsf_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Nsfe_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Sap_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Sap_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Sap_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Sms_Apu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Snes_Spc.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Spc_Cpu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Spc_Dsp.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Spc_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Spc_Filter.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Vgm_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Vgm_Emu_Impl.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Ym2413_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>Ym2612_Emu.cpp</fileName>
                            <fileName>gme.cpp</fileName>
                        </fileNames>
                    </source>


                    <!-- additional include path -->
                    <source>
                        <directory>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.h</include>
                        </includes>
                        <deployable>true</deployable>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Can anyone with an enormous heart please give me some pointers.  I think I hate maven :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a Maven plugin for eclipse. You could use that to build your server files and launch it on localhost:8080. [This](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) tutorial should help you.